# What is the minimum thickness of foam board when insulating a basement

Tags: insulation, basement

What is the minimum thickness of the foamboard insulation that can be used when insulating a concrete basement wall when it comes to moisture control and temperature control?

Obviously thicker is better but it is also more cost prohibitive. Would a product like this http://www.homedepot.com/p/Owens-Corning-FOAMULAR-1-4-in-x-4-ft-x-50-ft-R-1-Fanfold-Insulation-Sheathing-21UM/100320301 (http://www.homedepot.com/p/Owens-Corning-FOAMULAR-1-4-in-x-4-ft-x-50-ft-R-1-Fanfold-Insulation-Sheathing-21UM/100320301) work as a basement wall insulator or is it too thin?

Additonally is there any concenrn with insulating a few moths prior to framing aside from aesthetics?

Comment: Where are you from?

Comment: @DMoore I am in the souther indiana region. RIght at the border of 4 and 5 on the chart below.

Answer (score 2):

Building codes will tell you this information. First, find your climate zone on this map:
[image]

Then cross-reference that with the table here: http://publicecodes.cyberregs.com/icod/irc/2012/icod_irc_2012_11_sec002.htm

Look at the first number under "BASEMENT WALL R-VALUE". That's the minimum R-value you need to be safe. Divide that number by the per-inch R-value of the foam you want. For example, if you live in zone 4, it says you need a minimum of R-10 on the walls. If you're using low-density Home-Depot-sourced R-3.8 EPS foam (a sheet of white beads, like styrofoam), that means you need 2.7 inches of EPS  to be code-legal and safe. Round up to 3 inches. XPS (blue or purple and smooth) is R-5, so you could get away with only two inches of XPS. But XPS is more expensive per R-value, worse for the environment, and degrades to R-4.2 over time, so in general, EPS is preferred. Seal the edges of the boards with little bits of spray foam, caulk, and tape (as appropriate). Seal them to the floor too. You can use the same method to insulate the rim joists. Just make sure everything's sealed up tight so no inside air can reach the walls and rim joists.

The product you reference is 1/4" thick and only rated R-1 per board. So you would need ten sheets of this product to reach R-10. It would be much more cost-effective to buy a single 2 or 3" board. I believe Home Depot sells 1-3" sheets of both EPS and XPS so you should be able to find what you need there. You can use multiple layers, and in fact this is slightly preferred because you can stagger the boards' seams.

With continuous insulation like this, you don't even need to frame an interior wall, which will save you time and money. Just install drywall right over the insulation using Tapcon screws going into the concrete wall behind the insulation. I recommend using cementboard instead of drywall for the bottom few feet for flood resistance. If you insist on framing a wooden wall over the foam, use pressure-treated lumber.

There is no issue with leaving the insulation exposed for a while besides fire safety. Polystyrene foam (which is what both XPS and EPS are made of) will ignite and melt at relatively low temperatures. You are required to cover them with an ignition barrier like drywall. You can wait to do this as long as you're comfortable with, or as long as your inspector allows you to, if this is an inspected project.

Comment: Do both XPS and EPS offer vapor protection or is a vapor barrier preferred? Also without the framing do you just typically mount recepacles on the outside of the drywall?

Comment: Both offer enough for the situation, but it's not vapor protection you're primarily looking to block but rather air movement. Do not add a dedicated vapor barrier like a sheet of plastic or anything. Without studs, you can either add receptacles over the drywall using conduit, or dig channels into the foam to hide conduit below the drywall.

Comment: Without Studs, when you do interior walls do you just push the framing up against the exterior walls and connect the drywall? Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: You don't need any framing at all. I've given you a method to make a wood-free basement wall that is flood-proof. For interior partition walls, use mortared 4" concrete blocks covered with a skim coat of lime plaster gauged with a little gypsum in it. No need for wood at all, and you'll have a basement that laughs at floods. And it *will* flood eventually, because it's a basement.

Comment: I'd suggest still framing walls...metal studs preferably. Easier to attach drywall to than dealing with tapcons plus gives you a bit more freedom in terms of running mechanicals and electrical.

Comment: And to emphasize what iLike said about vapor barriers...the entire point of using foam boards in a basement is to *prevent* a vapor barrier. Foam is actually permeable and acts as a vapor retarder--but not barrier. As iLike state's, the main purpose is to prevent air migration so moist air doesn't come in contact with the cold concrete and condenses. But if it does...there's still enough permeability for it to eventually dry.

Comment: Are you really suggesting to someone that they put drywall over XPS and use tapcons to secure the drywall?

Answer (score 1):

The info that iLikeDirt is giving you is for basements.  A "basement" by building definition is completely below grade.  In most regions in the US there is no need to insulate below grade, as the summer season gains offset winter issues.  Also foam board on the inside of a basement in my opinion is overkill and a waste of time in most regions.

Edit after gaining region:  I live in the northern part of zone 4.  I finish 7-10 basements a year and have just done 2 in the past 4 years for my own home.  Putting in foam board isn't even a thought unless you have issues with your basement walls (cracking, cinder block, thin pour, whatever).

What I have been doing for 4-5 years is ROXUL on the walls starting with one foot below grade, stuff all the joists and outside walls with ROXUL and spray foam (cans) for gaps.  Building inspectors have been very happy with this.  Also just from personal usage, my home got this treat and in my opinion my basement runs too warm.   We have the vents permanently closed in the winter.  Framing should be 1/2-1" from wall, moisture will have plenty of run to ventilate, and unless you have a leak you will never have issues.

Also you never never never attach drywall to XPS or the like.  There just isn't a good way to may this sandwich (gluing is the only choice), electric/plumbing can't be ran, and the XPS can wick into the drywall.  If you want drywall by XPS at the very very least you attach 1x to XPS and run drywall on these - I would never do this either.

Comment: DMoore: Thanks for comments on XPS not being attached to drywall. I received another comment on a different thread indicating the opposite! Do I have to attach XPS to the foundation stone (fastener type?) and then leave a small gap between teh XPS and the studs/drywall? Thanks...